# TypeError: The argument 'cell' (<keras.layers.recurrent.RNN ..) is not an RNNCell: 'output_size' property is missing, 'state_size' property is missing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using TensorFlow.Keras and writing a sequence to sequence model for the time series data classification task. In this model, I am using multilayer BiLSTM in the encoder part and multilayer stacked LSTM cells in the decoder part. I have written the following lines of code:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, layers, feature_extract, bidirectional=False):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()

    self.n_layers=len(layers)
    self.lstm_cells = [LSTMCell(hidden_dim) for hidden_dim in layers]
    self.feature_extract=feature_extract
    self.bidirectional=bidirectional

    def call(self, x):
       # dimension of x: input shape=[batch_size, time_step, embedding_dim]
       x=tf.reshape(x, [-1, 3000,1])
       network=self.feature_extract(x)
       print("after feature extraction")
       x= tf.reshape(network, (-1, max_time_step, network.shape[-1]))
       print("after feature reshape", x.shape)

       if self.bidirectional:
           encoder = Bidirectional(RNN(self.lstm_cells, return_state=True))
           encoder_outputs_and_states = encoder(x)
           bi_encoder_states = encoder_outputs_and_states[1:]
           print(len(bi_encoder_states))
           encoder_states = []
           for i in range(int(len(bi_encoder_states)/2)):
               temp1 = concatenate([bi_encoder_states[i][0],bi_encoder_states[self.n_layers + i][0]], axis=-1)
               temp2 = concatenate([bi_encoder_states[i][1],bi_encoder_states[self.n_layers + i][1]], axis=-1)
               temp=[temp1, temp2]
               encoder_states.append(temp)
       else:  
               encoder = RNN(self.lstm_cells, return_state=True)
               encoder_outputs_and_states = encoder(x)
               encoder_states = encoder_outputs_and_states[1:]
       return encoder_outputs_and_states, encoder_states

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
      def __init__(self, char2numY, dec_units, batch_sz, attention_type='luong',  bidirectional=False):
      super(Decoder, self).__init__()
      self.batch_sz = batch_sz
      self.dec_units = dec_units #must be two times of enc_units
      self.attention_type = attention_type

      # Embedding Layer
      #self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

      #Final Dense layer on which softmax will be applied
      self.fc = Dense(len(char2numY), use_bias=False)

      # Define the fundamental cell for decoder recurrent structure
      if bidirectional:
         decoder_cells = [LSTMCell(hidden_dim*2) for hidden_dim in layers]
      else:
         decoder_cells = [LSTMCell(hidden_dim) for hidden_dim in layers]
 
      self.decoder_lstm = RNN(decoder_cells, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)

      #self.decoder_rnn_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(self.dec_units)

      # Sampler
      self.sampler = tfa.seq2seq.sampler.TrainingSampler()

      # Create attention mechanism with memory = None
      self.attention_mechanism = self.build_attention_mechanism(self.dec_units, 
                                                          None, None, self.attention_type)

      # Wrap attention mechanism with the fundamental rnn cell of decoder
      self.rnn_cell = self.build_rnn_cell(batch_sz)

      # Define the decoder with respect to fundamental rnn cell
      self.decoder = tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(self.rnn_cell, sampler=self.sampler, 
                                                                         output_layer=self.fc)


      def build_rnn_cell(self, batch_sz):
          rnn_cell = tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(self.decoder_lstm, 
                              self.attention_mechanism, attention_layer_size=self.dec_units)
          return rnn_cell

      def build_attention_mechanism(self, dec_units, memory, memory_sequence_length, 
                                                                      attention_type='luong'):
          return tfa.seq2seq.LuongAttention(units=self.dec_units, memory=memory, 
                                                                  memory_sequence_length=None)

     def build_initial_state(self, batch_sz, encoder_state, Dtype):
         decoder_initial_state = self.rnn_cell.get_initial_state(batch_size=batch_sz, 
                                                                                  dtype=Dtype)
         decoder_initial_state = decoder_initial_state.clone(cell_state=encoder_state)
         return decoder_initial_state

    def call(self, inputs, initial_state):
        x = inputs
        outputs, final_states, final_sequence_lengths = self.decoder(x, 
                                            initial_state=initial_state, sequence_length=None)
        #dec_outputs, _final_state, _final_sequence_lengths = 
                                      tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder,impute_finished=True)
        logits = outputs.rnn_output
        return outputs, final_states

layers=[128, 128]
batch_sz=32
max_time_step=10  # 5 3 second best 10# 40 # 100
output_max_length=10 + 2  # max_time_step +1
sample_x = tf.random.uniform((batch_sz, max_time_step, 3000))
encoder = Encoder(layers, feature_extract, bidirectional=True)
# sample input
#sample_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
encoder_outputs_and_states, encoder_states= encoder(sample_x)
print ('Encoder output shape: (batch size, sequence length, units) 
{}'.format(len(encoder_outputs_and_states)))
print ('Encoder h vecotr shape: (batch size, units) 
{}'.format(len(encoder_states)))


#output
after feature extraction
after feature reshape (32, 10, 2560)
4
Encoder output shape: (batch size, sequence length, units) 5
Encoder h vecotr shape: (batch size, units) 2

# testing decoder

dec_units=256
embedding_dim=256
output_max_length=max_time_step +2
vocab_size=7 # no. of class + <SOD> + <EOD>= 5+1+1=7
decoder = Decoder(vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units, layers, batch_sz, 'luong', bidirectional=True)
sample_x = tf.random.uniform((batch_sz, output_max_length))
decoder.attention_mechanism.setup_memory(sample_output)
initial_state = decoder.build_initial_state(batch_sz, encoder_states, tf.float32) 
print(sample_x.shape)
sample_decoder_outputs, _ = decoder(sample_x, output_max_length, initial_state)  

print("Decoder Outputs Shape: ",sample_decoder_outputs.rnn_output.shape)
```

I am getting the following error

```
  TypeError: The argument 'cell' (<keras.layers.recurrent.RNN object at 
  0x7f66b6c5c850>) is not an RNNCell: 'output_size' property is missing, 
  'state_size' property is missing.
```

I am not able to understand the reason behind this error.
Please help me in fixing this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this help https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/networks_seq2seq_nmt

Comment: Yes, It helps a lot but I want to build a double-layer Bi-LSTM encoder and double-layer LSTM  decoder.